# I am trying to read an image and convert it to double in python , I am using cv2 library

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I tried doing the same thing in Matlab by reading the image using imread and then converting it to type double using im2double, how can I achieve the same thing in python or cv2 library?.

I tried using

```py
img=imread('pathofmyimage')
double=np.asarray(img,dtype=np.float64)
```

but I am not sure of this method

Comment: it's just a *numpy array*. does knowing that help? perhaps add some code to your question, as recommended by [ask].

Comment: I tried using image=imread(path) then ,double = np.asarray(image,dtype=np.float64) but I don't know if this is the right way to do it

Comment: @QusaiJaserAl-Buqaeen try `print(double.dtype)` to see the [data type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html) of your array after conversion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could just say

```py
float_img = img.astype(np.float64)
```

But your way works too. The result from both methods will be equal.

To find out the type of an array, look at its `.dtype`. `imread()` returns `np.uint8` by default, with values ranging 0 to 255, but it can return arrays of other types, if given the right flag. That is detailed in the docs.

After conversion with `astype` (or `asarray`), the values will still be in the range of 0 to 255, just in a different data type. If you need them to be ranged 0.0 to 1.0, you'd need to scale the array (divide/multiply).